# Is it possible to ensure that Laravel jobs actually run at round times?

Tags: laravel, cron, laravel-scheduler, laravel-jobs

I want to perform certain job exactly at round times, precisely every 30 minutes, for example:

```
- 00:00
- 00:30
- 01:00
- ...
- 12:00
- 12:30
- 13:00
- ...
```

In the `Kernel.php`, I have this job...

```
$schedule->command('mycommand:sender')
            ->everyThirtyMinutes();
```

... and in in the `crontab`, I have this command...

```
* * * * * cd /www/webapp && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Apparently everything is ok, but if I stop the service or restart the server, this instructions, either in `Kernel` or even in`Crontab`, is correct for, for example, the server or service became available, at "12:29", I know the command will execute from "minute to minute", but "something" from these instructions will know that the next execution "should" be at 12:30 or the way it is, will run "30 minutes" after 12:29, therefore, 12:59?

Although it may seem irrelevant, but I have tasks in my system, that the needs to perform at these "round times", because the task "execution time" determines what will be performed.

Answer (score 0):

Add this instead ->everyThirtyMinutes();

```php
cron("*/30 * * * *")
```

This will be execute from now:

> at 2019-12-04 18:00:00
>   then at 2019-12-04 18:30:00
>   then at 2019-12-04 19:00:00
>   then at 2019-12-04 19:30:00
>   then at 2019-12-04 20:00:00

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try, but only so I can understand better. So, based on your suggestion, then this `everyThirtyMinutes()  `will always run every 30 minutes, but not round time, but then `cron("*/30 * * * *")` has to have different property?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of run in cron every minute and check the logic in php why do not make `cron` to run every 30 minutes?

```
0,30 * * * * cd /www/webapp && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: It's an alternative, but I have other tasks, including one every 15 minutes and others at static times (always at 8:30 and 22:30). My fear is to lose these times, because an execution outside the expected time, the information that comes, no longer matters.

Comment: I do not see any problem with this. At the end `cron` is about to run scheduled jobs. And it run them quite well and precise. The tolerance can be only few seconds

Comment: If I change anything, either in the `job` or in the `kernel`, I will need to restart the command `artisan queue:work --daemon`, since this one is running in the background `(php artisan queue:work --daemon --tries=0 > storage/logs/jobs_queue.txt &)`?

Comment: Have no idea as I am sysadmin. But probably yes